# Derivative of $(\ln x)^e$

Tags: derivatives, logarithms

In Randall Munroe's *What If*, he says that "if you want to be mean to first-year calculus students, you can ask them to take the derivative of $(lnx)^e$" He says, as I would expect, that the result "looks like it should be $1$ or something, but it's not." Why is this? And what's the actual answer?

Comment: $e^{ln(x)}$ is x, this is just the natural log raised to a number.

Comment: @Tyroshipleasurebarge Look again at the question :)

Answer (score 5):

By the chain rule:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}x}\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]^e&=\frac{e\left[\ln\left(x\right)\right]^{e-1}}{x}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks! What rule says I can't simplify that to just `x` before using the power rule?

Comment: Because $\left(\ln x\right)^e\neq e^{\ln x}$, so it can't be simplified.